# Insert into Table if ID doesn't exist, otherwise skip

Tags: sql, pentaho, kettle

I am using Kettle Pentaho data integration. I need to skip inserting IdN column from first table (first db) if it already exists int second table (second db).

In my kettle's design I've got Table Input (which returned me some rows).

I've need to select distinct IdN column from that returned rows, and to insert them (all distinct ids) into second table of second database (so I avoid duplicating ids).

I've tried with this code in *execute sql statements* :

```
INSERT INTO {SecondTable}
SELECT DISTINCT (IdN)
```

But returned with error:

> Invalid column name 'IdN'.

And what confuses me, is that I have checked parameter IdN into "Field name to be used as argument" under "Execute SQL section" node of my kettle's design, which is valid column name I've got returned from previous table input node.

Comment: where is your `FROM` part of the `SELECT`?

Comment: I'm getting data from previous "Table Input" node, I don't know how could I specify "from previous sql executed data rows"?

Comment: I think you should still use the table in the `FROM`

Comment: Yeah I would but there's problem because I'm limited on 1 connection, and I have got 2 different databases which I need to transfer data between so If I select FROM first, I would lose option to INSERT INTO second one.

Comment: Have you tried the `Insert/Update` step?

Comment: I've succeeded using "Unique rows" step before inserting to Table Output, it will simply avoid existing column's values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be sure I am understanding. You are trying to write a query to select the idN column from one database into a table in another database. If so the query should look like this

```
    Insert into db1.dbo.tableName1(colname)
    Select Distinct colname From db2.dbo.tablename2
```

Comment: There's little problem one connection in kettle specifies one database, and I am limited to only one connection, so I buffer data somehow and to transfer it.

Comment: When using the table in the other database in the format [DatabaseName].[Schema].[TableName], it should be able to connect to it even from the connection to the other database. Have you tried it? If it is on another server it will be [Server].[DatabaseName].[Schema].[TableName]

Answer (score 1):

I've succeeded using "Unique rows" step in Kettle, it will do exactly what I wanted, just specify columns on which to check value existence.